# javascript or jquery for loop doesn't work

Tags: for-loop

I have this:

```
<script>
$("#P1").on("blur", function(){$("#Y1").val(getClass(this));});
$("#P2").on("blur", function(){$("#Y2").val(getClass(this));});
$("#P3").on("blur", function(){$("#Y3").val(getClass(this));});
$("#P4").on("blur", function(){$("#Y4").val(getClass(this));});
</script>
```

I'd like to change it to a for loop using jquery:

```
<script>
var i = null;
for ($i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
$("#P$i").on("blur", function(){$("#Y$i").val(getClass(this));}); 
}
</script>
```

But it doesn't work. How come?

Comment: try to replace $i with i. why you are using $ ?

Comment: You need to change to $("#P"+$i) as selector. Currently, jquery is looking for control with id="P$i" which obviously u aren't looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script>
var i;
for (i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
$("#P" + i).on("blur", function(){$("#Y" + i).val(getClass(this));}); 
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
 for (var $i = 0; $i < 4; $i++) {
 $("#P"+$i).on("blur", function(){$("#Y"+$i).val(getClass(this));}); 
 }
</script>
```